# Convert openssl command in ruby language using OpenSSL-Gem

Tags: ruby, openssl

i'm going crazy

I need to convert this openssl command

```
openssl smime -verify -in mysignedfile.xml.p7m -inform der -noverify -out simplefile.xml
```

into Ruby / RoR language. It's working as expected in console but I can't find the way to use it in ruby.

looking at the OpenSSL document, I can not succeed

this is an example of code

```
myfile = File.read "mysignedfile.xml.p7m"
OpenSSL::PKCS7::read_smime(myfile)
```

Response:

```
OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7Error: no content type
```

The file was successfully opened (i can read it), but i think read_smime expect for some value as content_type

Comment: could  you provide the contents of `mysignedfile.xml.p7m`?

Comment: thanks @LeśnyRumcajs for reply, the file type is "data", opening it with a text editor i can see in the middle the xml content, and on top and bottom of the file there is part of signature (i suppose). I prefear to non publish it here for pricavy issue. can you suggest me some commands helping you to inspect file?